# Prolog - getting only one answer

Tags: prolog

I have this program in Prolog:

```
foo([],L2,L2).
foo(L1,[],L1):-L1=[_|_).
foo([H1|T1],[H2|T2],[H1|T3]):-foo(T1,[H2|T2],T3).
foo([H1|T1],[H2|T2],[H2|T3]):-foo([H1|T1],T2,T3).
```

I run the query

```
foo([1,2],[a],R).
```

I got :

```
[1,2,a]
```

and when I typed a semicolon (`;`) to get more answers, I got `False`... but when I run it by hand using backtracking I also got the answer `[1,a,2]`.

I don't understand why the compiler gives only one answer.

Comment: You have a syntax error here: `foo(L1,[],L1):-L1=[_|_).`. The last `)` should be a `]`.

Comment: And in SWI-Prolog you get 3 answers: `?- foo([1,2],[a],R).
R = [1, 2, a] ;
R = [1, a, 2] ;
R = [a, 1, 2] ;
false.`

Comment: thanks for the third time... :-)

Comment: Just a tip: On many platforms you can enter SPACE in stead of ; which is often easier to find on the keyboard.